# favorite button in android not working properly

Tags: java, android, xml

Hii i'm making an app where i have small heart image onclick of that image i've set an `onclick listener` so when i click on that image it is replaced by another red coloured heart image.

so my problem is when i again click on red heart image it doesnt turn to its normal state which is blank heart vector image as i'm new in android i dont have much knowledge please if someone can guide.

**my code for image onclick**

```
  @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(FeedViewHolder holder, int position) {
    int image_id = images[position];
    //holder.background_image_layout.setImageDrawable(null);
    //holder.background_image_layout.setImageResource(image_id);
    holder.background_image.setBackgroundResource(image_id);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return images.length;
    }
    public static class FeedViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CustomTextViewMedium first_text,second_text,third_text,fourth_text,fifth_text,sixth_text,
                seventh_text;
        ImageView favourite_image;
        CardView primary_card;
        LinearLayout background_image;
        ImageView background_image_layout;
        CircleImageView profile_image;
        public FeedViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            background_image = (LinearLayout)itemView.findViewById(R.id.background_image);
            primary_card = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.primary_card);
            first_text = (CustomTextViewMedium)itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_text);
            second_text = (CustomTextViewMedium)itemView.findViewById(R.id.second_text);
            third_text = (CustomTextViewMedium)itemView.findViewById(R.id.third_text);
            fourth_text = (CustomTextViewMedium)itemView.findViewById(R.id.fourth_text);
            fifth_text = (CustomTextViewMedium)itemView.findViewById(R.id.fifth_text);
            sixth_text = (CustomTextViewMedium)itemView.findViewById(R.id.sixth_text);
            seventh_text = (CustomTextViewMedium)itemView.findViewById(R.id.seventh_text);
            favourite_image = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.favourite_image);
            background_image_layout = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.background_image_layout);
            profile_image = (CircleImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
            favourite_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(favourite_image.isPressed()){
                        favourite_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart);
                        favourite_image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    }
                    else {
                        favourite_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp);
                        favourite_image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    }
                }
            });


        }
    }
```

Comment: use `else if(favourite_image.isPressed()){
                        favourite_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp);
                        favourite_image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                    }`

Comment: Doesnt work i tried it already when i click it first time then only the if condition works @Abhinav Gupta

Comment: yes i do have..

Comment: ok just hold on a moment

Comment: hi @Abhinav i have sent you the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if` condition like this :-

first globally define like this :-

```
boolean imageChange = true;
```

then do this in `setOnClickListener` like this :-

```
  favourite_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        if(imageChange ){
                            favourite_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart);
                            favourite_image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                            imageChange = false;                        
                           }else {
                                favourite_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp);
                                favourite_image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                                imageChange = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: @Gotiasits first I have used if else condition then i have used boolean by myself I saw your answer right now.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that `favourite_image.isPressed()` is not persistent state of the View. It will be `true` only while user holds its finger on the view.

To overcome this you have two similar options:

### Option #1

Instead of checking `isPressed` you can check some other state, for example `isSelected`. Since this is `ImageView` you probably need to set the state manually on click.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(favourite_image.isSelected()){
                        favourite_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_heart);
                        favourite_image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                        favourite_image.setSelected(false)
                    }
                    else {
                        favourite_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_favorite_border_black_24dp);
                        favourite_image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
                        favourite_image.setSelected(true)
                    }
                }
```

### Options #2

Use some simple `boolean` to keep track of the selected state, and set/chec its values similarity to above code.